# RAM and CPU requirement for timer jobs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

Is there a guideline available about how many custom timer jobs can we run using specific RAM and CPU?

I am developing an application which may require to create 10+ timer jobs each running at 1 minute interval so I wanted to know how do I make sure that they run without problems.

Comment: My experiance is that running multiple timerjobs at a high interval is no problem, but that do depends what you are actually doing in/with the timerjob.

Comment: My timer job will call external API and then update list item. Each call may take 0.5 seconds to complete and there may be 1500 records in each file so one file will take around 12 mins to complete. I plan on using Job lock type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such guidance as it will heavily depend on the type of operations your timer job is doing. Get a Load Runner (up to 50 seat testing it is free now) and test your system without timer jobs and with them you will be able to see the impact they are having for a system under load.

Answer (score 1):

I may recommend you to increase the interval between consecutive timer jobs .

There is no specific guideline for RAM or CPU utilization for Timer jobs .

You say that the requirement is for 10+ timer jobs running at an interval of 1 minute .

Now consider this , suppose one of the Timer job utilizes a lot of RAM and there is a high utilization spike on the CPU , the rest of the timer jobs are going to get impacted any way .

Instead if there is **sufficient time interval between the timer jobs** say like for example 10 minutes ,it gives your system enough time to respond and come out of any problems.

A lot of things can happen like **Memory leakage ,Timer jobs getting stuck** etc.

So carefully plan this.

I would recommend keeping at least 10 minutes interval between the jobs so that there is not impact on the system .